# WPF Component Obscures Subcomponents in Designer

Tags: .net, wpf, viewbox, visualdesigner

Some components like the viewbox are displayed in the visual designer as solid boxes. However, they can contain subcomponents.  To view the subcomponents I comment out the viewbox.  When I'm done I have to remove the comments to restore the functionality.  It's rather annoying.  Is there any way to permanently make the viewbox invisible (or behave like the dockview/stackview components) in the visual designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Controls without a Visual Design-time.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165609.aspx)

Comment: Great. Next version of Visual Studio I suppose... thanks for the info.